# How to determine ORACLE_HOME from PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, path, oracle-home

Is it possible to determine where Oracle is installed using pure PL/SQL?

Use case:
In order to call an external C library, I need to know its exact path (for the `create library` call). My DLL will reside in Oracle's BIN directory, but I can't hard-code the path of the DB installation in my scripts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows and Oracle 10g, this works:

```
SELECT  
substr(file_spec,1,instr(file_spec,'\',1,3)) 
FROM dba_libraries 
WHERE library_name='DBMS_SUMADV_LIB'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE
 RetVal VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  dbms_system.get_env('ORACLE_HOME', RetVal);
  dbms_output.put_line(RetVal);
END;
```

NOTE:  It is likely you that you will not have permission to this package by default.

Comment: Unfortunately, on my database, `DBMS_SYSTEM` is not installed.

Comment: Have you considered using a DIRECTORY?
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY APP_ORACLE_HOME AS '/u01/oracle/10.1.2';

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Oracle 12c, you can use the `SYS_CONTEXT` function: [*Oracle docs*](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions199.htm#SQLRF06117)

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','ORACLE_HOME'));
END;
/

/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1
```